# Connection between $\operatorname{Spec}A$ and a zero set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is the continuation of [Terminology: $\operatorname{Spec}A\subset \mathbb{A}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192774/terminology-operatornamespeca-subset-mathbba2)

Probably I should have asked there what I'm going to ask now, but since there are already two answers there, it's no reasonable to add additional questions by editing the original one.

So, recall the following definition of an affine plane conic: it is $\operatorname{Spec}A\subset \mathbb{A}^2$ where $A=k[x,y]/(f)$ and $f$ a quadratic polynomial with no multiple factors. Intuitively, a conic is the zero set of something. Is there any explanation why a set of prime ideals is "the same as" the zero set of something? Of course one may consider the sero set of a set of ideals, but there is no term "zero set" in the above definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $k$ is algebraically closed, then maximal ideals (which are all prime) of $A$ correspond to maximal ideals $\mathfrak m=(x-a,y-b)$ of $k[x,y]$ such that $f\in\frak m$, which is the same as saying that $f(a,b)=0$. So you can indeed think of maximal ideals as "points of affine space where $f$ vanishes" without any harm, i.e. you still get all the "classical" points when you use prime ideals; but then you get some extra points (prime ideals which are not maximal). You can think of these extra points as "extra information" about your space, though it's hard to see why you'd want this extra information until you start learning about schemes in depth.

Comment: You should probably include that the result you cite is Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.  +1, though.