# The spectrum of the quotient as a subset of the spectrum of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, terminology

Suppose we have a ring $R$, an ideal $I$, and a multiplicative set $S$.

I understand that there are maps $f:Spec(R/I)\to Spec(R)$ (a "point" $[P]_I=P+I$ gets sent to preimage $P$ under the quotient map) and $g: Spec(S^{-1}R)\to Spec(R)$ (the prime ideal $S^{-1}P$ gets sent to its preimage under the localization map).

Now when somebody says that $Spec(R/I)$ and $Spec(S^{-1}R)$ are (closed and open) *subsets* of $Spec (R)$, what exactly do they mean? $Spec(R/I)$ and $Spec(S^{-1}R)$ are not subsets of $Spec (R)$. Do those statements mean that the image of $f$ (and of $g$) are closed/open subsets of $Spec (R)$ (and if so, are $f$ and $g$ always injective)? Or how to formalize those statements?

Comment: Yes, they are homeomorphisms onto their images and it is these images one asserts are open/closed.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2192774)

Comment: @ThePuix And what does it mean that the Zariski topology on $Spec(R/I)$ coincides with the subspace topology induced by the inclusion to $Spec(R)$? I understand that there is the Zariski topology on $Spec(R/I)$, but I don't know what the Zariski topology on $image(f)$ is. $image(f)$ only has the subspace topology induced from $Spec(R)$, what exactly is the other topology on $image(f)$ that is claimed to be equal to the subspace topology?

Comment: @user538518 Since they're homeomorphic, a subset $U\subseteq$Spec($R/I$) is closed iff it's image is closed in Spec($R$).

Answer (score 1):

You're identifying $X=\mathrm{Spec}(R/I)$ with the image of $f$, the latter of which is a subset of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$. So $X$ has two topologies: (1) the Zariski topology, and (2) take the subspace topology on the image of $f$, and use the bijection $\mathrm{image}(f) \simeq X$ to transfer this topology to $X$.

It's all a big abuse of notation to make things more clean to state. In algebraic geometry, it's very nice to think of $\mathrm{Spec}(R/I)$ as a subset of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$, since the former is the "vanishing locus" of the ideal $I$.